# Clear a terminal Screen in Google's Secure Shell

Tags: linux, shell, google-chrome-extension

How can I clear the terminal screen in Google's chrome extension [Secure Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=en)?

When I type `clear` the screen appears to be blank, but I still can scroll up and see all the unwanted output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
<ctrl> + <shift> + K
```

I found this [here](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/GuLFLWpntFE).